# Filling Dropdownlist on a value coming from another Dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a Dropdown of `issuedate` these dates are filling in my dropdown by applying some filters on it in a http get method

```
ViewBag.PMID1 = new SelectList(db.PRIMKT_MAST.Where(z => z.PRODUCT_ID == j && z.REC_VERIFIED == 0 && z.VERIFY_LOCK == 0 && z.TRTYPE == i), "PMID", "ISSUE_DATE");
```

This is my dropdownlist.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ISSUE_DATE, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
          @Html.DropDownList("PMID1", null, new { @onchange = "FillTenor()" })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ISSUE_DATE)
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to select `AUCTIONID` in a table where this dropdownlist is filling on basis of issue date like `select auctionid where issuedate = dropdown selected value`

When we get `auctionid` I want to take this `auctionid` and search in other table and fill another dropdown on basis of this `auctionid` like
`select Tenors(i want to select this value) where auctionid is (whatever we get from dropdown)`
This is my second Dropdownt list which I want to fill

```
     <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TENOR_ID, "TENOR_ID", new { @class     = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TENOR_ID,
new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "AUCDT_ID", "TENOR_ID"),
              "Select Tenors",
              new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BRANCH_ID)
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.AUCTION_ID = new SelectList(db.AUCTION_DATA, "AUCTION_ID", "PRODUCT_ID");
    ViewBag.CUSTOMER_ID = new SelectList(db.CUSTOMERs, "CUSTOMER_ID", "CUSTOMER_NAME");
    ViewBag.PMID = new SelectList(db.PRIMKT_MAST, "PMID", "PRODUCT_ID");
    ViewBag.BRANCH_ID = new SelectList(db.BRANCHes, "BRANCH_ID", "BRANCH_DESC");
   //ViewData["ListofIssueDate"] = db.PRIMKT_MAST.Where(z => z.PRODUCT_ID == Session["Product_Id"] && z.REC_VERIFIED == 0 && z.VERIFY_LOCK == 0 && z.TRTYPE == Convert.ToInt32(Session["Trtype"])).Select(z => z.ISSUE_DATE);
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Trtype"]);
    string j =Convert.ToString( Session["Product_Id"]);
    ViewBag.PMID1 = new SelectList(db.PRIMKT_MAST.Where(z => z.PRODUCT_ID == j && z.REC_VERIFIED == 0 && z.VERIFY_LOCK == 0 && z.TRTYPE == i), "ISSUE_DATE", "ISSUE_DATE");
    return View();

}
```

my Ajax Call.

```
    @section script {
        <script>
            function FillTenor() {
                var IssueDate = $('#PMID1').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("FillCity", "PrimaryMarket")',
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: { IssueDate: $("#PMID1").val() },
                    success: function (Tenor) {
                        $("#TENOR_ID").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                        $.each(Tenor, function (i, AUCDATA_TENORS) {
                            $("#TENOR_ID").append(
                                $('<option></option>').val(AUCDATA_TENORS.AUCDT_ID).html(AUCDATA_TENORS.TENOR_ID));
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    }
```

My onchange Method

```
[HttpGet]        
public ActionResult FillTenor(DateTime? IssueDate)   
{
        var auctionid = db.PRIMKT_MAST.Where(c => c.ISSUE_DATE == IssueDate).Select(c=>c.AUCTION_ID).ToList();
        var Tenor = db.AUCDATA_TENORS.Where(c => c.AUCTION_ID ==( auctionid[0])).Select(c => c.TENOR_ID);

        return Json(Tenor, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYuwl.png)

Comment: Search MVC cascading dropdownlist (refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for an example)

Comment: Use Javascript for cascading drop down list, capture `PMID1`'s value and make ajax call to load second drop down list's value.

Comment: i have make a ajax call and my function is working onchange of dropdownt event '        public ActionResult FillTenor(DateTime? IssueDate)
        {
            var auctionid = db.PRIMKT_MAST.Where(c => c.ISSUE_DATE == IssueDate).Select(c=>c.AUCTION_ID).ToList();
            var Tenor = db.AUCDATA_TENORS.Where(c => c.AUCTION_ID ==( auctionid[0])).Select(c => c.TENOR_ID);
           
            return Json(Tenor, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }'  but it is giving me exception @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Please show your complete ajax call, your controller code and thrown exception on your existing post, I'll try to investigate and provide solution detail(s) as possible.

Comment: i have updated my question please check @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: In what line or statement that exception occured? I suspected `var Tenor = db.AUCDATA_TENORS.Where(c => c.AUCTION_ID ==( auctionid[0])).Select(c => c.TENOR_ID);` become source of your exception. I'll post a solution if I know where the problem roots.

Comment: yes on this line my exception occurs because i think in tenor there is query coming not a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method` with `get_Item(Int32)` means that you have certain array value assignment inside lambda expression that potentially returning null or empty value, thus it cannot be translated to proper SQL statement to fill your cascaded drop down list.

I suspected this expression generated that exception:

```
var Tenor = db.AUCDATA_TENORS.Where(c => c.AUCTION_ID ==( auctionid[0])).Select(c => c.TENOR_ID);
```

Suggested lambda expression:

```
// common practice handling array value(s) into lambda:
// use a variable outside lambda to hold array value(s),
// then pass that variable inside the lambda
var auctionId = auctionid[0]; // this may improved to check against null or empty value
var Tenor = db.AUCDATA_TENORS.Where(c => c.AUCTION_ID == auctionId).Select(c => c.TENOR_ID);
```

NB: This behavior also applies to array from a class containing properties.

Any improvements and suggestions welcome.

Reference: [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ... get_Item(Int32)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15695825/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-get-itemint32)

Comment: Thankx Man you are a Life Saver :D